# How to choose randomly pivot Element?

Tags: java, pivot, quicksort

I am making **QuickSort** algorithm. I had used last element as pivot. And it is Working Correctly. My problem is i want to choose pivot element Randomly(From user). How to do it?

Code using last pivot:

```
int partition(int arr[], int start, int end) 
{ 
int pivot = arr[end];  
int i = (start-1);  
`enter code here`for (int j=start; j<end; j++) 
    { 
        if (arr[j] < pivot) 
        { 
            i++; 
            int temp = arr[i]; 
            arr[i] = arr[j]; 
            arr[j] = temp; 
        } 
    } 

    int temp = arr[i+1]; 
    arr[i+1] = arr[high]; 
    arr[high] = temp; 

    return i+1; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to prompt the user to select an index to use as the pivot?

Comment: I'd find it cool, if the user can choose an index, but something like `Math.random` will do the job too.

Comment: Yes. I want to take index number from user.

Comment: So you're really asking how to accept input of an integer from the user?

Comment: This isn't as simple as it appears at first blush. The pivot in a quick sort implementation changes from iteration to iteration. The initial pivot can be any index of the array from beginning to end, inclusive, but as the recursion goes deeper, the pivot can and will change. So are we talking about a user selected initial pivot only, or are we going to ask for a new pivot on each recursive call? In that case, we're not just prompting for input, but restricting it to prevent stack overflow.

Comment: No i want to ask pivot element from user initially.

Comment: Pivot _element_ or pivot _index_?  You've said both in different comments; which one is it?

Comment: Sorry. The index of pivot.